# C# TAP async Multiple enqueue Delay then dequeue all

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a system where a method is called with an object  and the database is written with a different object with a list of the first  .

Currently :

```
private async Task SaveAMessage(Messsage message)
{
    var messages = new List<Message>();
    messages.Add(message);
    var envelope = new Envelope();
    envelope.messages = messages;
    await _db.Save(envelope);
}
```

But I can only run `_db.Save` every 1 second.

What is the [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  way of saying: *Add this item to the list and then save them all together after 1 second. Below I have some fake code that expresses what I wish I could write*.

**Javascript-y Pseudo Code:**

```
private List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
private int? valueCheckTimer;
private async Task SaveAMessage(Messsage message)
{
    messages.Add(message);
    if (valueCheckTimer) { 
        return;
    }
    valueCheckTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        var envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.messages = messages;
        await _db.Save(envelope);
        messages.Clear();
    },1000);
}
```

**How do I write C# code that acts the way the pseudo-code works?**

Comment: `new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }, null, 1000, 1000);`

Comment: edited to show the question.

Comment: Timer would just delay the code for 1 second and always run every second.  I want to only run when I have something.  I suppose I could use a guard condition to only save if messages.Any()

Comment: `save them all 1 second` Do you mean "save all messages every second" (which is what your JS code does), or "save all messages immediately and don't allow another save for at least a second", or "wait a second and then write all messages", or "wait at least one second, resetting the timer each time another message comes in"?

Comment: My JS waits 1 second then saves all then doesn't do anything until there's a new message. then waits for the full second.  thats ideal but i would also just rate limit to 1 cal;ll a second

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with just one small really simple change.  Add a `WhenAll` to `SaveAMessage` to await both `Save` as well as a call to `Task.Delay`:

```
private async Task SaveAMessage(Messsage message)
{
    var messages = new List<Message>();
    messages.Add(message);
    var envelope = new Envelope();
    envelope.messages = messages;
    await Task.WhenAll(_db.Save(envelope), Task.Delay(1000));
}
```

Now you can just loop through all of your calls to `SaveAMessage`, awaiting them all, and you can be sure that it waits until the previous save is done *and that at least a second has passed* before continuing.

If you sometimes don't need to wait a full second when using `SaveAMessage` elsewhere, then simply pull this change out and have whatever code you're using to save all of your messages await the `Task.Dealy` call.

Comment: @MarkKGreenway Sure it does, but if you don't call `SaveAMessage` until the task from the previous message's save completed, then the saves won't overlap, and there will be at least a second beteween saves, which is what you asked for.  I see no indication that there should be any less saves than your old code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of c# code (run as ConsoleApp):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task<string> SaveAMessage(string message)
        {
            var messages = new List<string>();
            messages.Add(message);
            return await save(messages);
        }

        private static Task<string> save(List<string> msg)
        {
            Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message " + msg[0] + " received...");
                Console.WriteLine("Message " + msg[0] + " running...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "Message " + msg[0] + " finally return.";
            });
            return task;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<string> first = SaveAMessage("Msg1");
            first.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Print " + x.Result));
            Task<string> second = SaveAMessage("Msg2");
            second.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Print " + x.Result));
            Task<string> third = SaveAMessage("Msg3");
            third.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Print " + x.Result));
            Task<string> fourth = SaveAMessage("Msg4");
            fourth.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Print " + x.Result));
            Task<string> fifth = SaveAMessage("Msg5");
            fifth.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Print " + x.Result));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This in no way adds the functionality requested, namely that the next call to `SaveAMessage` is not called quicker than 1 second from the previous call to `SaveAMessage` regardless of how long it takes `Save` to complete.  On top of that, in your main method you don't even have each call as a coninuation of the other, so you're performing them all concurrently.  **That's what he's trying to avoid doing**.